# Spring security how do admin perform every action which comes after (/admin/**) just using 1 intercept url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Spring security how do admin perform every action which comes after (/admin/**) just using 1 intercept url

Spring Security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">


<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/user**" access="permitAll" />

<!-- access denied page -->
<access-denied-handler error-page="/noaccess" />
<form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" authentication-success-handler-ref="customSuccessHandler"
username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
<logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
<!-- enable csrf protection -->
<csrf />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider user-service-ref="loginService" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="customSuccessHandler"  class="com.slp.pro.handler.CustomSuccessHandler" />

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: i think it's ".*" , but more specifically look at patterns

Comment: Now if i use "/admin/anyurl" does above code works or I have to use another intercept url

Comment: try it. Should work

Comment: It works for link  but I'm trying crud operation and it says   You are not authorized to access this page

Comment: I do not understand definition of crud operations ( i do know what crud is, I do not understand context), do you mean some different url?